# Cleaner jQuery If Statements

Tags: jquery, if-statement

This is a mess and does not work as planned. Banging head against wall. There must be a quicker and cleaner way to achieve this, i have 3 divs all with a "p" tag in each. If the values are between certain setpoint then i'm trying to implement a traffic light system by swapping img src's...

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                    $.get("db.php?phase=1", function(data){ $("#phase1 p").html(data); });
                    $.get("db.php?phase=2", function(data){ $("#phase2 p").html(data); });
                    $.get("db.php?phase=3", function(data){ $("#phase3 p").html(data); });
                    $.get("db.php?tstamp=1", function(data){ $("#tstamp p").html(data); });
            setInterval(function() {
                    $.get("db.php?phase=1", function(data){ $("#phase1 p").html(data); });
                    $.get("db.php?phase=2", function(data){ $("#phase2 p").html(data); });
                    $.get("db.php?phase=3", function(data){ $("#phase3 p").html(data); });
                    $.get("db.php?tstamp=1", function(data){ $("#tstamp p").html(data); });
            }, 60000);
            if ($("#phase1 p").val() < 400){
                    $("#phase1light").attr("src", "/phases/img/green.png");
            }
            else if (($("#phase1 p").val() > 400 && $("#phase1 p").val() < 500)){
                    $("#phase1light").attr("src", "/phases/img/amber.png");
            }
            else if ($("#phase1 p").val() > 500){
                    $("#phase1light").attr("src", "/phases/img/red.png");
            };
            if ($("#phase2 p").val() < 400){
                    $("#phase2light").attr("src", "/phases/img/green.png");
            }
            else if (($("#phase2 p").val() > 400 && $("#phase2 p").val() < 500)){
                    $("#phase2light").attr("src", "/phases/img/amber.png");
            }
            else if ($("#phase2 p").val() > 500){
                    $("#phase2light").attr("src", "/phases/img/red.png");
            };
            if ($("#phase3 p").val() < 400){
                    $("#phase3light").attr("src", "/phases/img/green.png");
            }
            else if (($("#phase3 p").val() > 400 && $("#phase2 p").val() < 500)){
                    $("#phase3light").attr("src", "/phases/img/amber.png");
            }
            else if ($("#phase3 p").val() > 500){
                    $("#phase3light").attr("src", "/phases/img/red.png");
            };
        });
```

HTML:

```
<div id="phase1">
            <p class="results"></p>
            <img id="phase1light" src="/phases/img/red.png" />
        </div>
        <div id="phase2">
            <p class="results"></p>
            <img id="phase1light" src="/phases/img/red.png" />
        </div>
        <div id="phase3">
            <p class="results"></p>
            <img id="phase1light" src="/phases/img/red.png" />
        </div>
```

HELP!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but it should work:

```
phasePath = '/phases/img/';

(function getTheData() {
    $.get("db.php?tstamp=1", function(data){ $("#tstamp p").html(data); });

    $("div[id^=phase]").each(function() {
        var phaseId = $(this).attr('id').substr(5);

        $.get("db.php?phase=" + phaseId, function(data){
            var phaseVal = data;

            if(phaseVal >= 500) {
                var phaseImg = 'red.png';
            } else {
                if(phaseVal >= 400) {
                    var phaseImg = 'amber.png';
                } else {
                    var phaseImg = 'green.png';
                }
            }

            $("p", this).html(data);
            $("img", this).attr("src", phasePath + phaseImg);
        });
    });
})();

setInterval(getTheData, 6000);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @benhowdle89: That is probably because the above code is being executed before your AJAX queries are completed. If you look at [this JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sEn2N/) you will see that the values are being read correctly, and the paths are being set correctly too.

Comment: excellent, got it, just wrapped a setInterval around the whole thing! Cheers

Comment: @benhowdle89: Glad to be of help ! Please see my updated answer. This will also do the AJAX requests and the image switching will not happen until the data is retrieved.

Comment: You might want to put brackets around the whole getTheData function (starting from the beginning of the `function` line, and then put `()` after it to make it run straight away, instead of waiting 6 seconds after the page loads.

Answer (score 1):

`.val()` on a p tag? http://api.jquery.com/val/. I don't think you're supposed to do that. Maybe you meant to use `.text()`? A straight replace should make it work.

As for cleaning it up a bit, use some functions:

```
var getPhase = function (phaseNum) {
  $.get("db.php?phase="+phaseNum, function(data){ $("#phase" + phaseNum + " p").html(data); setLights(phaseNum); });
}

var setLights = function (phaseNum) {

  if ($("#phase" + phaseNum + " p").text() < 400){
    $("#phase" + phaseNum + "light").attr("src", "/phases/img/green.png");
  }
  else if ($("#phase" + phaseNum + " p").text() > 500){
    $("#phase" + phaseNum + "light").attr("src", "/phases/img/red.png");
  }
  else {
    $("#phase" + phaseNum + "light").attr("src", "/phases/img/amber.png");
  }
}

(var getAllPhases = function () {
  for (var i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
    getPhase(i);
  }
})(); // execute the function immediately

setInterval(getAllPhases, 6000);
```

I've put a setLights() inside the success function because to me that seems to make sense. If that's not the way you wanted it, try it wherever else is relevant. And BTW, this is untested. If you're not able to resolve any errors, let me know and I'll see if I can help.

Comment: Thanks for this really appreciate it but if you see my edited Q then i've added a screen shot of what its coming out like!? bit random...